# org-mode, remove a tag from all marked entries

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to remove a tag from multiple entries at once.  It is the same tag on each of the entries.

I know how to show the entries with that tag.  I can "mark" some of them in the agenda view.  Now how can I remove a tag from all the marked ones?

BACKGROUND:

I have to do a release every little while.  I add a "RELEASE" tag to the TODO items that need to be done for that release.  When the release is ... released, then I need to untag all those entries and start over with keeping track of features for the next release.

I'd like to untag all those entries marked RELEASE in one shot, instead of visiting 15 or 20 items one by one and removing this RELEASE tag.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on what to do with this marking of the agenda items.  I discovered it by accident, maybe I am misunderstanding what it is for?

Comment: Would it be helpful to have the `RELEASE` tag removed automatically when the entry is marked `DONE`?

Comment: @erikstokes, no, I want to be able to mark it done so I can search for RELEASE and figure out how much is done and how much is left to do.  But thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

Once the items are marked, you can type B into the agenda todo list to do a "bulk" action.  One of the choices is to work on tags.

HOW I FOUND THE ANSWER (in case it helps someone else trying to figure out org-mode AND in case I did something wrong, someone can correct me).

In the agenda view where the TODO items with RELEASE were listed, I typed C-h k m to find out the name of the function that does the marking.  It is called org-agenda-bulk-mark.  Armed with that clue, I looked in org-agenda.el for functions (items marked "defun") with "bulk" in the name, and found org-agenda-bulk-action mapped to the 'B' key.  So I tried it, and it did what I want.

Comment: Here is a link to the manual that describes commands that are available relating to the agenda:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Agenda-commands.html

Comment: Thanks!  I did see that page, but I guess I never got as far as 2/3 of the way down.  Agenda has a lot of functionality!

Comment: Many years later, that manual page is now at: https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html